# relocation R_X86_64_32S against hidden symbol `_ZN5boost6detail15sp_counted_base7destroyEv' can not be used when making a PIE object

Tags: c++

**
Try to compile the code, there is no issue before.
I am using M1, this may happen after I update my laptop.
here is the error message

```
/usr/bin/ld: /home/sunrain/.linuxbrew/lib/libboost_log-mt.a(core.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against hidden symbol `_ZN5boost6detail15sp_counted_base7destroyEv' can not be used when making a PIE object
/usr/bin/ld: /home/sunrain/.linuxbrew/lib/libboost_log-mt.a(record_ostream.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against symbol `_ZTVSo@@GLIBCXX_3.4' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIE
/usr/bin/ld: /home/sunrain/.linuxbrew/lib/libboost_log-mt.a(severity_level.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against hidden symbol `_ZZN5boost3log12v2s_mt_posix3aux14lazy_singletonINS1_7sources3aux21severity_level_holderENS2_15thread_specificIPmEEE3getEvE29_boost_log_once_block_flag_43' can not be used when making a PIE object
/usr/bin/ld: /home/sunrain/.linuxbrew/lib/libboost_log-mt.a(thread_id.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.bss' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIE
/usr/bin/ld: /home/sunrain/.linuxbrew/lib/libboost_log-mt.a(exceptions.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against symbol `_ZTVN5boost3log12v2s_mt_posix13runtime_errorE' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIE
/usr/bin/ld: /home/sunrain/.linuxbrew/lib/libboost_log-mt.a(default_attribute_names.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.text' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIE
/usr/bin/ld: /home/sunrain/.linuxbrew/lib/libboost_log-mt.a(default_sink.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against hidden symbol `_ZTVN5boost3log12v2s_mt_posix5sinks3aux12default_sinkE' can not be used when making a PIE object
/usr/bin/ld: /home/sunrain/.linuxbrew/lib/libboost_log-mt.a(thread_specific.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIE
/usr/bin/ld: /home/sunrain/.linuxbrew/lib/libboost_log-mt.a(once_block.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.bss' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIE
/usr/bin/ld: /home/sunrain/.linuxbrew/lib/libboost_log-mt.a(trivial.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against hidden symbol `_ZZN5boost3log12v2s_mt_posix3aux14lazy_singletonINS1_7sources3aux16logger_singletonINS1_7trivial6loggerEEENS_10shared_ptrINS5_13logger_holderINS4_18severity_logger_mtINS7_14severity_levelEEEEEEEE3getEvE29_boost_log_once_block_flag_43' can not be used when making a PIE object
/usr/bin/ld: /home/sunrain/.linuxbrew/lib/libboost_log-mt.a(dump.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against hidden symbol `_ZN5boost3log12v2s_mt_posix3aux16g_hex_char_tableE' can not be used when making a PIE object
/usr/bin/ld: /home/sunrain/.linuxbrew/lib/libboost_log-mt.a(dump_avx2.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against hidden symbol `_ZN5boost3log12v2s_mt_posix3aux16g_hex_char_tableE' can not be used when making a PIE object
/usr/bin/ld: /home/sunrain/.linuxbrew/lib/libboost_log-mt.a(dump_ssse3.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against hidden symbol `_ZN5boost3log12v2s_mt_posix3aux16g_hex_char_tableE' can not be used when making a PIE object
/usr/bin/ld: /home/sunrain/.linuxbrew/lib/libboost_log-mt.a(attribute_name.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against hidden symbol `_ZZN5boost3log12v2s_mt_posix3aux14lazy_singletonINS1_14attribute_name10repositoryENS_10shared_ptrIS5_EEE3getEvE29_boost_log_once_block_flag_43' can not be used when making a PIE object
/usr/bin/ld: /home/sunrain/.linuxbrew/lib/libboost_log-mt.a(attribute_set.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against symbol `_ZNSt9bad_allocD1Ev@@GLIBCXX_3.4' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIE
/usr/bin/ld: /home/sunrain/.linuxbrew/lib/libboost_log-mt.a(attribute_value_set.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against symbol `_ZNSt9bad_allocD1Ev@@GLIBCXX_3.4' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIE
/usr/bin/ld: /home/sunrain/.linuxbrew/lib/libboost_log-mt.a(code_conversion.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.8' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIE
/usr/bin/ld: /home/sunrain/.linuxbrew/lib/libboost_log-mt.a(global_logger_storage.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.bss' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIE
/usr/bin/ld: /home/sunrain/.linuxbrew/lib/libboost_thread-mt.a(thread.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.text' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIE
/usr/bin/ld: /home/sunrain/.linuxbrew/lib/libboost_thread-mt.a(once.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.bss' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIE
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/request_handler_dispatcher_test.dir/build.make:95: bin/request_handler_dispatcher_test] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:188: CMakeFiles/request_handler_dispatcher_test.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:141: all] Error 2
```

any details solution? thank you!
**

Comment: Why do you set the `-fPIE` flag? Are you building a dynamic library?

Comment: looks like the message refers to the libboost, and not to your compiled objects

Answer (score 0):

You have to compile your static libboost with PIC/PIE too. You can not link a non-PIC static library to a PIE executable.

Comment: how can I do that?

Comment: That you have to look up in the build system for boost.

Comment: @HesterZhang I think a bigger problem is why you want to build with `-fPIE` to begin with? And why you need to link with the Boost static libraries rather than dynamic libraries?